# Save Calculated Value from Spawned Child Form to Parent After Button Click

Tags: c#, forms, winforms, datagridview

I have a Winforms Form and I spawn a Route Calculator in a DataGridView Control. After client inputs, it does the calculation and then updates a textbox on the same form after "Update" is pressed. How can I make it so that the value from this textbox in the spawned Form will transfer to an existing textbox on the spawned (child) form back to the parent and close the spawned form at after doing so.

The code below will spawn the child form:

```
DeliveryLocationCalculator form = new DeliveryLocationCalculator();
            form.Show();
```

What should go in the button2_Click (Save) button of the child form to make it transfer the textbox value and also close the child form after clicking

Comment: see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17032484/passing-data-between-3-separate-winforms) for how to wire events between different forms

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I understand
If you want transfer value of calculated result from `DeliveryLocationCalculator` form to the main form and then close `DeliveryLocationCalculator` form, then 
create public property in `DeliveryLocationCalculator` for saving result,

```
class DeliveryLocationCalculator 
{
    //...
    public decimal FinalResult { get; set; }
}
```

And use `.ShowDialog()` method for open calculator `DeliveryLocationCalculator` form in the modal mode.
After `DeliveryLocationCalculator` form will be closed, you can read value of property `FinalResult`, before form will be disposed

```
//Code in then main form
using form = new DeliveryLocationCalculator()
{
    form.ShowDialog();
    this.TextBoxOnMainForm.Text = form.FinalResult.ToString();
}
```

From MSDN about [ShowDialog method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c7ykbedk(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: This helped me solve this problem much quickly. Thanks. I also voted up!