# How would I change the BackColor of a panel from form 2 (for example) using a button from another form?

Tags: c#, winforms

For example, I would like to make the `BackColor` of one of the panels of `form 2` red but I want to do it from another form using a button.

Comment: Hi, show us what you have got

Comment: You need a reference to the existing form.  Then a public modifier for the control or a form property that can access it.

Comment: Consult [Passing Data Between WinForms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17032484/).

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try this https://stackoverflow.com/a/17047470/4571435

Assume FirstChildForm as Form 1 and SecondChildForm as Form 2. Add button to FirstChildForm and Panel on the SecondChildForm.